# How can a conference paper publication be guaranteed? Is such a "guarantee" even possible?

Tags: publications, conference

My cousin, a freshman in college, recently heard from a private education institute that a conference publication will be guaranteed if she joins their research tutoring program. **In their program description, they mention that their student will be promised to have their paper published in Scopus indexed conferences.**

This intrigued my curiosity- how can someone promise that a college student who has never done any research before will be granted a conference publication? I don't think they would dare to write the paper on behalf of the student.

So here comes my question - **how can a conference paper publication be guaranteed?**

Comment: Sounds like a misunderstanding. Can you reproduce the exact information from the institute? In academia, there no such thing as "granting conference publications", contributions are submitted to conferences and assessed by independent peer reviewers, which may or may not lead to the publication of the paper. Your follow-up question is very broad. To a big extent, the purpose of a PhD is to train you to get your conference paper published.

Comment: I assume that the paper will be submitted, and, if accepted, they might "grant" the travel to the conference? Might that be their meaning?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper the institute advertised that students who join their program will be guaranteed to have a paper published at one of the Scopus indexed conferences.

Comment: Your question had attracted some close votes, so I rewrote the title and eliminated the second question, which was too broad to be answerable. I also recommend you give a better answer to @lighthousekeeper's question: rather than summarizing their advertisement, it would be better to provide the exact words, so we can rule out a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that difficult. All that happens is that a private university pays an association (IEEE or something else) to host a conference. Then since they host it, they can choose to publish conference proceedings, with a journal sponsor. That is how most special issues work.

A more comprehensive answer [is here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/42237/58270)

Comment: This was my thought as well, but OP claims they were promised publication at a Scopus-indexed conference.

Comment: Wouldn't make that much of a difference right? If a major journal is a sponsor, they can easily have a special issue covering just the conference proceedings; which means the proceedings are also "Scopus Indexed" since the parent journal is.